# MongoDb id generator is not working

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a simple need `generate string ID if field is null before inserting`. It works fine if property has name `Id`, but otherwise it doesn't.

I have following class:

```
public abstract class CampaignBase
{
   [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(StringObjectIdGenerator))]
   [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
   public string CampaignId { get; set; }
}

public class Campaign : CampaignBase {}
```

Now when I insert `MyData` in the database I get `null` instead of generated id. It seems that these attributes just are not applied, because if property has `Id` name then if works fine and attribute can change actual data layout (`string`/`objectid`/etc).

This is how I save it:

[image]

`campaign` and `campaignBase` are referencing to the same object, so don't mind it.

Where UpdateOptions:

```
protected static UpdateOptions UpdateOptions => new UpdateOptions
{
    IsUpsert = true
};
```

And here it is: null is arriving:

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: Just tried this and works fine locally, what version of the driver are you using? also do you have the rest of the code?

Comment: I'm saving it via `ReplaceOne,` because I want to save it it it doesn't exist. See edit

Comment: It seems that insert works, but ReplaceOne - doesn't.

Comment: `ReplaceOne` will use the query for the ID as the key to insert the record, you should really just break this down into a replace and an Insert.

Comment: @KevinSmith I actually need `Replace` behaviour here. I mean `save an object and overwrite if it already exist`.

Comment: Explain how you need to replace when the document doesn't exist yet?

Comment: If it doesn't exist then it's just an insert. It's just like upsert where all fields must be upserted. It's how the old `Save` method from the legacy driver has been working. But I have understood my problem, thank you. I'm gonna write my own extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just break the commands down into what it's doing instead of trying to mix concerns:

```
var myItem = new MyItem() {Name = "Bob"};

if (myItem.MyId == null)
{
    mongoCollection.InsertOne(myItem);
}
else
{
    mongoCollection.ReplaceOne(x => x.MyId == myItem.MyId, myItem);
}
```

Replacing on an id of `null` will just insert null as the `_id` for the document.

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up with following extension:

```
public static void Save<T, TProperty>(this IMongoCollection<T> collection, T item, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> idFunc) where TProperty : class
{
    var id = idFunc.Compile()(item);
    if (id == null)
    {
        collection.InsertOne(item);
    }
    else
    {
        var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Equal(idFunc.Body, Expression.Constant(id, typeof(TProperty))), idFunc.Parameters);
        collection.ReplaceOne(expression, item);
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
CampaignsCollection.Save(campaign, c => c.CampaignId);
```

Thank @KevinSmith for idea

---

Here is a bit more complicated implementation, but it's more resilent, it has better client interface and performance due to caching

```
public static class MongoExtensions
{
    public static void Save<T>(this IMongoCollection<T> collection, T item)
    {
        if (item == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(item));

        if (MongoSaveCommandHelper<T>.ShouldInsert(item))
        {
            collection.InsertOne(item);
        }
        else
        {
            var expression = MongoSaveCommandHelper<T>.GetIdEqualityExpression(item);
            collection.ReplaceOne(expression, item);
        }
    }

    private static class MongoSaveCommandHelper<T>
    {
        private static readonly Expression<Func<T, bool>> IdIsEqualToDefaultExpression;
        private static readonly Func<T, object> GetId;
        public static Func<T, bool> ShouldInsert { get; }

        static MongoSaveCommandHelper()
        {
            var members = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
            var idProperty = members.SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsDefined(typeof(BsonIdAttribute)))
                             ?? members.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name.Equals("id", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            if (idProperty == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Id property has not found");

            var idPropertyType = idProperty.PropertyType;
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
            var idPropertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, idProperty);
            var getIdFuncExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(Expression.Convert(idPropertyAccess, typeof(object)), parameter);

            GetId = getIdFuncExpression.Compile();
            IdIsEqualToDefaultExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Equal(idPropertyAccess, Expression.Default(idPropertyType)), getIdFuncExpression.Parameters);
            ShouldInsert = IdIsEqualToDefaultExpression.Compile();
        }

        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetIdEqualityExpression(T item) => 
            (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)new IdConstantVisitor(GetId(item)).Visit(IdIsEqualToDefaultExpression);
    }

    private class IdConstantVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private readonly object _value;
        public IdConstantVisitor(object value) => _value = value;
        protected override Expression VisitDefault(DefaultExpression node) => Expression.Constant(_value, node.Type);
    }
}
```

Generally, it just insert an item if `Id` field is equal to `default(PropertyType)`, otherwise it replace an item with specified id.

Here it is how we can use it:

```
CampaignsCollection.Save(campaign);
```

This code handles everything for us. No mistaken invalid ID column, no extra typing, just save it, period :)

Comment: Very similar to the `db.col.save` within js - https://pastebin.com/Z4SSSzmZ

Comment: @KevinSmith I have mentioned `Save` method above ;) But it got removed in driver version 2.X. So I needed a replacement. But there is no one built in.

Comment: @KevinSmith small edit has been made. It's more generic and resilent version. Take it if required :) For example, original code didn't handle situation when we had default `ObjectId`. It could just insert empty Id in the database, because `ObjectId.Empty != null`